# Is it possible that a simply connected domain and a Jordan curve's interior have same boundary but not equal?

Tags: general-topology

There is a bounded simply connected domain $\Omega$ whose boundary $\partial\Omega$ is a Jordan curve $\gamma$ (simple closed curve). In Jordan Curve Theorem, we have known that the Jordan curve splits the plain into two simply connected components, the bounded one called "interior". My question is whether $\Omega$ is exactly the interior of the Jordan curve $\gamma$? Is it possible that $\Omega$ and the interior have same boundary but $\Omega$ is not equal to the interior? (Using math words is that whether $\partial\Omega=\gamma$ can imply $\Omega= int(\gamma)$.)

The proposition above seems like obvious. I tried hard to prove but failed. Could anyone help me solve this tough problem? Thanks very much!!

Comment: Do you know the Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: I know, but the thing I confused is whether the simply connected domain bounded by a Jordan curve is unique? Does there exist a simply connected domain whose boundary is the Jordan curve but not the curve's interior?

Comment: IF you know the JCT, the complement of the Jordan curve has exactly two connected components, one of which is bounded (interior) and one of which is unbounded (exterior). You already know that a) $\Omega$ is connected, b) $\Omega$ is in the complement of $\gamma$ and c) $\Omega$ is bounded, so there's only one option left.

Comment: You are right, but I think you still miss the explanation that why $\Omega$ is the COMPONENT. Is it possible that $\Omega$ properly contains ($\subset$)in one of two components and its boundary is $\gamma$?

Comment: Now that I understand your question (from that last comment), I quite like it +1. Let me suggest that you edit your post to incorporate this last comment, so that everyone who reads your post understands more clearly what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post, hoping someone can give me a rigorous answer.

Comment: Just a minor detail, but the exterior is not simply connected, just connected.

Comment: The exterior still can be seemed as simply connected, if you put it in the $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$

Comment: Oh yeah, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concern is a valid subtletly, which I glossed over in my comments. So here's a complete argument. Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be open, connected and bounded, such that $\partial\Omega$ is a Jordan curve (we do not need to assume that $\Omega$ is simply connected - actually, that follows from these hypotheses). The Jordan Curve Theorem tells us that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\partial\Omega=U\cup V$, with $U,V$ connected, open and disjoint, $\partial U=\partial V=\partial\Omega$, $U$ bounded and $V$ unbounded.

Now, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\partial\Omega$ (since $\partial\Omega=\overline{\Omega}\setminus\mathrm{Int}(\Omega)=\overline{\Omega}\setminus\Omega$ is disjoint from $\Omega$ by $\Omega$ being open) is connected, so either $\Omega\subseteq U$ or $\Omega\subseteq V$. Let $A\in\{U,V\}$ be the one such that $\Omega\subseteq A$. Note that $A=\Omega\cup A\setminus\Omega$ is a disjoint union and $\Omega\subseteq A$ is open. Now, $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset$ since $A$ is open (same argument as before), but $\partial A=\partial\Omega$. This implies $A\setminus\Omega=A\setminus\overline{\Omega}$, since $\overline{\Omega}=\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$. Thus, $A\setminus\Omega\subseteq A$ is open too. The connectedness of $A$ now forces $\Omega=\emptyset$ or $A\setminus\Omega=\emptyset$. The former is excluded for trivial reasons ($\partial\emptyset=\emptyset$ would not be a Jordan curve), so $A\setminus\Omega=\emptyset$, i.e. $A\subseteq\Omega$. In total, $\Omega=A$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, it now follows *a posteriori* that $\Omega=A=U$, i.e. $\Omega$ is the interior of $\partial\Omega$.

If you want a slightly more geometric picture for the above argument, we can utilize path-connectedness of $A$ instead of connectedness of $A$ (these are equivalent for open subsets of the plane). Then, you can argue that if you were to take a path in $A$ from a point in $\Omega$ to a point in $A\setminus\Omega$, this path would have to cross $\partial\Omega=\partial A$, contradicting $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset$. I leave the details as exercise.

Comment: What an amazing proof!